# PCRE PartialMatch dynamic number of groups

Tags: c++, c++11, pcre

My app has user defined regular expression patterns which may contain up to 3 capturing groups. Is there a better way to implement the following code?

```
std::string glyph1, glyph2, glyph3;

switch (regex.NumberOfCapturingGroups())
{
    case 0:
    default:
        found = regex.PartialMatch(word);
        break;
    case 1:
        found = regex.PartialMatch(word, &glyph1);
        break;
    case 2:
        found = regex.PartialMatch(word, &glyph1, &glyph2);
        break;
    case 3:
        found = regex.PartialMatch(word, &glyph1, &glyph2, &glyph3);
        break;
}

if (found) {
    // ...
}
```

Unfortunately, the returned value is false if the regex would match but there were less capturing groups then requested.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list or a vector for this problem. Instead of overloading the function make one with a parameter `vector<std::string> glyph` and a `int n` for the `regex.NumberOfCapturingGroups()`.

```
vector<std::string> glyph;
regex.PartialMatch(word, glyph, regex.NumberOfCapturingGroups());
if (found) {
    // ...
}
```

Then just use `glyph[i]` to access elements.

Comment: While I like the idea, I'm quite sure this is not how pcrecpp is implemented (this method definition does not exist in pcre-8.36) and I don't really want to add my own code to pcre.